# Why does yarn download packages always from the internet?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and I noticed that  `yarn install` **always** downloads packages from the internet. Why does yarn not have a preference for already downloaded packages that are available in the cache?

The [source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/v0.24.2/src/cli/index.js#L36) of `yarn` says:

```
commander.option('--prefer-offline', 'use network only if dependencies are not available in local cache');
```

I execute `yarn cache dir` and it even returns a directory, so there is a cache available for my packages. So why would `yarn` need to make a single connection to the internet if the cache is up-to-date, not speaking of downloading the same stuff again and again?

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/

Comment: Did you lock your dependencies, or are you using range versioning like `^1.0.0`? Because if the latter: yarn (and npm) will always ask the internet for the latest semver compatible version, and depedencies update patch and minor versions _a lot_, especially for bigger more popular packages.

Comment: Thanks so much! *facepalm*, I only used "^".. Is there any way to lock my versions but being open to "newer" versions by using `yarn upgrade` without upgrading every single dependency version manually?

Comment: In addition, the connections to the internet are fine, but it also seems to download the packages all the time, even if there is no newer package available

Comment: you might have to ask this on the yarn issue tracker - if you see it redownloading packages that you already have in your cache, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: pnpm is another package manager that is cache-first.

Comment: Wow, pnpm is really fast. I could accept that as an answer